# How to get mouseup to fire once mousemove complete

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

It seems that `mouseup` events are only fired when they are not in conjunction with a `mousemove`.  In other words, push down on the left mouse button and let go, and `mouseup` is fired.  But if you drag across the image and then let go, no `mouseup` is fired.  Here is an example that shows this behavior:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Out">
    <img id="Img" src="http://sstatic.net/so/img/logo.png" width=500>
</div>
<script language=JavaScript>
    $(function() {
        $(document).bind("mouseup",function() {alert("UP");});
        //$("#Out").bind("mouseup",function() {alert("UP");});
        //$("#Img").bind("mouseup",function() {alert("UP");});
    });
</script>
```

If you load this, and click and let go, "UP" will alert.  However, if you drag and then let go, no UP is fired.

How can I have `mouseup` fire when `mousemove` is completed, or how can I inspect the `mousemove` event to determine that the left mouse button is now off?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is a pattern I use *alot*, works generally very well on all things relating to mousemove. The mouseup event is binded when the user clicks mousedown, this forces it to fire when the user lets go of the mouse button, no matter how much it's moved.

```
$('#element').mousedown(function(e) {

    // You can record the starting position with
    var start_x = e.pageX;
    var start_y = e.pageY;

    $().mousemove(function(e) {
        // And you can get the distance moved by
        var offset_x = e.pageX - start_x;
        var offset_y = e.pageY - start_y;

        return false;
    });

    $().one('mouseup', function() {
        alert("This will show after mousemove and mouse released.");
        $().unbind();
    });

    // Using return false prevents browser's default,
    // often unwanted mousemove actions (drag & drop)
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Nice. It works, but only once. I made a quick change and got it to function for the whole page infinitely. http://jsbin.com/ajidi It can probably be done even better from there, but that's a pretty cool solution, I think.

Comment: this looks good in isolation, hopefully I can integrate it into the real deal, then I will check this as the answer

Comment: Surely you don't want to cancel mousedown, with all of its side-effects.  Chances are you just want to listen to both mouseup and dragend, and treat them both as mouseup.

Comment: This work's great. I wasn't able to get $() to work so I replaced it with $('body'). The one nitpick is that if you drag off the screen, the user has to click again - in which case you can check e.which in mousemove and end the dragging there

Comment: Concise and effective.  Can be simplified even further if you just want to call a function on mouseup.  

$('#element').mousedown(function () { $(document).one('mouseup', mouseReleased); return false; });

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget to namespace your events otherwise all event handlers will be unbound:

```
$('#element').bind('mousedown.namespace', function(e) {
    $(document).one('mouseup', function() {
        callback_func();
        $(document).unbind('mousedown.namespace');
    });
 });
```

Comment: I really NEED to thank you! I was completely lost and clueless for a long time, wondering why a mouseup event was not firing... THIS comment brought light back to life!

Comment: Great solution. I tried a lot of other alternatives for a cross-element mousedown-mouseup situation without success. Adding `click` to `one`'s events completed my needed implementation, for situations when the user doesn't drag the mouse outside the binded elements.

Answer (score 1):

As of JQuery 1.4 you need to substitute $('document') for $().  In fact, I'm using this to make a menu inside a JQuery UI Dialog, which seems to trap mousemove events.  So I simply substitute my container div for $() (which looks something like $('#myContainerDiv')).  This seems to work fine too.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and this worked for me:

```
$(document).on("dragend", function(e){
  $(e.target).trigger("mouseup");
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found that when I set my text as unselectable using the below CSS, the `mouseup` event is inhibited as well -- perhaps this will help someone else.

```
-moz-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue with KineticJS objects. Using kinetic's `dragend` instead of `mouseup` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem. Even after I add `e.preventDefault()` in the mousedown handler, it is still not resolved.

Finally, I find that if I turn off the following codes in my mousemove handler, my mouseup handler is called normally.

```
     mouseDragArea.css({
         top: dragAreaPos.y + 'px',
         left: dragAreaPos.x + 'px',
         width: Math.abs(mouseCurPos.x - mouseClickPos.x) + 'px',
         height: Math.abs( mouseCurPos.y - mouseClickPos.y ) + 'px'
     });
```

mouseDragArea is a programatically created element, which has a dotted border to show the rectangular area click-dragged by mouse:

```
    mouseDragArea = $('<div id="mouse-drag-area"></div>');
```

Then, I've realized that this `#mouse-drag-area` element is ABOVE the original element that handles the mouseup event. So after adding the following css declaration to `#mouse-drag-area`, it is sorted:

```
    pointer-events:none;
```

In another word, the crux is about which element you are setting your mouseup handler for.