# Mouseup event over flash object not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, jquery-events

I have got this script working from [How to get mouseup to fire once mousemove complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909760/how-to-get-mouseup-to-fire-once-mousemove-complete-javascript-jquery?tab=active#tab-top) working within the jQuery (document) scope.

Later on I added a flash object inside the body. and when I click on the flash object the mousedown event fired, mousemove event fired, but not the mouseup event which where I want to unbind the mousemove.

But when I click on non Flash area, mousedown works, mousemove works, and mouseup also works. It works like I wanted it to in Chrome, but not in Firefox.

Here are the codes, and I called `handleMouseDown` in `$(document).ready`

```
handleMouseDown: function () {
    jQuery(document).mouseup(function() {
        Log("unbind.");
        jQuery(document).unbind('mousemove');
    }); 

    jQuery(document).mousedown(function(e) { 
      Log('click');
      // You can record the starting position with
      var start_x = e.pageX;
      var start_y = e.pageY;

      jQuery(document).mousemove(function(e) {
          // And you can get the distance moved by
          var offset_x = e.pageX - start_x;
          var offset_y = e.pageY - start_y;

          Log('moves') ;
          return false;
      }); 

      // Using return false prevents browser's default,
      // often unwanted mousemove actions (drag & drop)
      return false;
  }); 
}
//firebug method log calls
function Log(str) {
    if (typeof(console.log) == 'function') console.log(str);
}
```

Comment: it works like i wanted it to in chrome. but not in firefox.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little bit tough to handle.

First off any flash object will capture all input. This means any mouse or keyboard events are within the flash object! While keyboard input is only captured when the element has focus, mouseUp will still happen "in" the flash object.

Second off, the only solution I can think of, is to overlay all flash objects with a foreground invisible div when mouveUp should get triggered. Might work... might not, but in theory it should.

Comment: i was thinking to do this too. would be my last resort

Answer (score 0):

You could place your mouse up code in a separate function that you can call from your JavaScript handler and an ExternalInterface call from Flash, when the mouse button is released over the Flash object.  Of course, this only works if you can edit the Flash source.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this problem like this:

```
$('object').live('mousedown', function() {
    alert('I was clicked');
});
```

only `.bind()` didn't do the job, probably because the object is inserted via swfobject...

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but doesn't seem to have a working answer so I'll just say how I got around it as it's still an issue today.  Whilst the mouseup event doesn't seem to fire over flash object the generic 'click' event does, if you're keeping track of your 'up' and 'down' status you should be able to use it to get what you want.  Super basic example:

```
$(document).on("mousedown", function () {
    mouseButtonStatus = "down";
});

$(document).on("mouseup", function () {
    mouseButtonStatus = "up";
});

// This little bodge gets around the issue with FireFox and the mouseup event
$(document).on("click", function () {
    if (mouseButtonStatus === "down"){
        mouseButtonStatus = "up";
    }
});
```

Needless to say scope your variables appropriately etc...

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use `MouseEvent.buttons` property, which is **Firefox** specific and since it is a **Firefox** quirk. This property is not available in **Safari** for example. Here is the code to detect whether the left button is pressed, note `touchmove` check to avoid triggering on touch devices:

```
if ( e.buttons != 'undefined' && e.type != 'touchmove'  && !(e.buttons & 1 ) ) 
bMouseDown = false;
```