# rotating div with mouse move

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, css

I have the following code to rotate a div. By mousedown event on the image in the upper-right corner of the same div. I want the div to rotate till mouse up. logically I believe the code is fine but it works after a click. Instead of mouseup the rotation stops when I click on an other item. I think on dragging after mouse down the browser tries to drag the image but I need help.. thanks in advance :)

```
fl_rotate: false,
rotdivs: function() {
    var pw;
    var oThis = this;
    $('.drop div img').mousedown(function(e) {
        oThis.destroyDragResize();
        oThis.fl_rotate = true;
        return;
    });
    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
        if (oThis.fl_rotate) {
            var element = $(oThis.sDiv);
            oThis.rotateOnMouse(e, element);
        }
    });
    $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
        if (oThis.fl_rotate) {
            oThis.initDragResize();
            var ele = $(oThis.sDiv);
            ele.unbind('mousemove');
            ele.draggable({
                containment: 'parent'
            });
            ele = 0;
            oThis.fl_rotate = false;
        }
    });
},
rotateOnMouse: function(e, pw) {
    var offset = pw.offset();
    var center_x = (offset.left) + ($(pw).width() / 2);
    var center_y = (offset.top) + ($(pw).height() / 2);
    var mouse_x = e.pageX;
    var mouse_y = e.pageY;
    var radians = Math.atan2(mouse_x - center_x, mouse_y - center_y);
    var degree = (radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 100;
    //            window.console.log("de="+degree+","+radians);
    $(pw).css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
    $(pw).css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
    $(pw).css('-o-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
    $(pw).css('-ms-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
}​
```

Comment: Can you create a http://jsfiddle.net/ with some example ?

Comment: Did you post all relevant code?

Comment: can you console.log the events to see if they happen when you think they should happen? from what you wrote I understand is that the first mousedown event fires only after a click and subsequently the second click activates the mouseup event which disables the rotate because the fl_rotate is set to true. This however makes it sound like mouseup event fires before mousedown?!?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem was that when the native drag event (that dragged the image) was fired (on mouse down) it was preventing the mouse up event to be fired. So you just need to prevent the default action of the mouse down event.

Here you have a working example:

HTML:

```
<div class="drop">
    <div>
        <img src="http://www.belugerinstudios.com/image/picturethumbnail/FunnyCatFootballIcon.JPG"/>
    </div>
</div>​
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // the same as yours.
  function rotateOnMouse(e, pw) {
      var offset = pw.offset();
      var center_x = (offset.left) + ($(pw).width() / 2);
      var center_y = (offset.top) + ($(pw).height() / 2);
      var mouse_x = e.pageX;
      var mouse_y = e.pageY;
      var radians = Math.atan2(mouse_x - center_x, mouse_y - center_y);
      var degree = (radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 100;
      //            window.console.log("de="+degree+","+radians);
      $(pw).css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
      $(pw).css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
      $(pw).css('-o-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
      $(pw).css('-ms-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
  }

  $('.drop div img').mousedown(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevents the dragging of the image.
    $(document).bind('mousemove.rotateImg', function(e2) {
      rotateOnMouse(e2, $('.drop div img'));
    });
  });

  $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
    $(document).unbind('mousemove.rotateImg');
  });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rwBku/13/

I have used jquery's [namespaced events](http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events) so you can unbind only the mousemove event that you want to.

Please note that the rotation of the image is buggy, but I really didn't look at that method.

Answer (score 2):

There is a lib for this. Works standalone or as jQuery plugin https://github.com/PixelsCommander/Propeller

Answer (score 0):

I think this stack overflow question answers your question [How to get mouseup to fire once mousemove complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909760/how-to-get-mouseup-to-fire-once-mousemove-complete)

The trick is to "ecapsulate" the mousemove and mouseup events in the mousedown event.