# CSS3 transform rotate using mouse position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to rotate a div element using CSS3 "transform:rotate".
I want to get the degree from mouse position, like tracking the mouse.

How can i achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Use JavaScript to track the mouse and update the style.

Comment: yes, but how do i convert mouse position to the rotate degree?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check

http://jsfiddle.net/arunberti/fSgPf/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // the same as yours.
  function rotateOnMouse(e, pw) {
      var offset = pw.offset();
      var center_x = (offset.left) + ($(pw).width() / 2);
      var center_y = (offset.top) + ($(pw).height() / 2);
      var mouse_x = e.pageX;
      var mouse_y = e.pageY;
      var radians = Math.atan2(mouse_x - center_x, mouse_y - center_y);
      var degree = (radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 100;
      //            window.console.log("de="+degree+","+radians);
      $(pw).css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
      $(pw).css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
      $(pw).css('-o-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
      $(pw).css('-ms-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
  }

  $('.drop div img').mousedown(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevents the dragging of the image.
    $(document).bind('mousemove.rotateImg', function(e2) {
      rotateOnMouse(e2, $('.drop div img'));
    });
  });

  $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
    $(document).unbind('mousemove.rotateImg');
  });
});
```

Comment: what should i do to achieve the same affect, with one change, rotate on bottom left transform-origin?

Comment: **Duplicate** of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11051676/rotating-div-with-mouse-move

Comment: also the prefixed `.css` are not needed jQuery does that out of the box.