# CSS3 transform rotate using mouse position - second phase

Tags: javascript, html, css

I received this perfect answer:

[[CSS3 transform rotate using mouse position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17827782/css3-transform-rotate-using-mouse-position][1])
[CSS3 transform rotate using mouse position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17827782/css3-transform-rotate-using-mouse-position)

but still, i need another tweak, same solution, but rotate on a different origin, like transform-origin: left bottom.

What should be modified?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use : 1) transform-origin: left bottom; (2) transform-origin:center center; 3) transform-origin: right bottom;

Answer (score 0):

This may be help you :

syntax :

```
transform-origin: x-axis y-axis z-axis;
```

**where x-axis :**
Defining where the view is placed at the x-axis. Possible values:

```
left
center
right
length
%
```

**where y-axis :**
Defining where the view is placed at the y-axis. Possible values:

```
left
center
right
length
%
```

**where z-axis :**
Defining where the view is placed at the z-axis. Possible values:

```
length
```

Example :

```
transform: rotate(45deg);
transform-origin:20% 40%;
```

Comment: thanks, please take a look at the attached link, i need the same result but with different origin

Comment: using javascript mouse movement event

Comment: You can use as follow :  $(pw).css("-webkit-transform-origin", 50% 50%);

Comment: for bottom left use bottom left instead of 50% 50%

Comment: thanks, but this is not what i mean,. please look at the attached link. there is a rotate element using mouse movement. i have a problem modifying its rotate to a different origin