# Javascript: windows,document,body mouseup listen issue while dragging <a>

Tags: javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/TMmgt/4/

html:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">some text</a>​
```

js:

```
var down=false;    

$('a').mousedown(function(){
    down=true;
});

$('a').mouseup(function(){
    down=false;
});

$('a').mousemove(function(){
    if(down){
       console.log('Mouse is still down!');
       // do something        
    }
});

$(window,document,'body').mouseup(function(){
    down=false;
});​
```

Drag link anywhere in the body and release, then move cursor over the link again. 
Mouse move will still be showing that `down` is `true`, because `mouseup` was not triggered and haven't changed it to `false`. Then just click anywhere in body and move over link again. Now `down` is `true`

Any workaround for this issue?

As i understand, it's because of default browser `<a>` drag behavior.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TMmgt/5/

Comment: I don't believe they're supposed to be corresponding, matching bookends. A `mouseup` is fired over an element, not if it's half a page away (as far as I understand it...?). I would expect it to a mouseup it didn't observe. That's what `mouseout` is for.

Comment: I still want to be able to drag left and right. Dragging inside narrow carousel is kinda uncomfortable.

Comment: @AspiringAqib thanks mate. Didn't know it's removing this behavior as well. Please post your answer as actual post so i can accept it.

Comment: possible re-post answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019190/mouseup-event-on-drag  and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909760/how-to-get-mouseup-to-fire-once-mousemove-complete

Comment: I didn't say you couldn't, just not to rely only on one event to handle that issue. The fix is using `mousemove` (I think `mouseout` probably would be more appropriate). Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/KzWkS/8/) of events being inconvenient and not overlapping the way you wish they would. You just find another way, including checking. each. and. every. event. to see where and when and what order it fires. Tedious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/TMmgt/5/

```
var down=false;


$('a').mousedown(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    down=true;
});

$('body').mouseup(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    down=false;
    check();
});

$('a').mousemove(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(down){
       console.log('Mouse is still down!');
       // do something        
    }
});

function check(){
    if(down==false) {
    console.log('Mouse is up!');
}
}
```

​

Comment: $(window).on("mousemove", ...) and $(window).on("mouseup", ...) triggers events even if mouse events are happening outside of the body or even outside of the browser window. Using only body might be problematic for example if user moves cursor away from the body and releases the button.